# Capturing the arguments of execve system call

Tags: c, system-calls, strace, ptrace

I am trying to use ptrace and capture the arguments that are getting passed to a execve system call. But when I use `PTRACE_GETREGS` and try to get the arguments for `SYS_execve` I am getting 0 for all the register values. Can you tell me as how strace gets me all the args that get passed ? I tried reading its source but they are using some structure apparently which I didn't get its use completely. Is there a simpler way ??

Comment: Show us the code you are using.

Comment: @PavanManjunath: http://pastie.org/3838018 this is a part of the code.

Comment: @PavanManjunath: do you want a working code?

Comment: @bi0s.kidd0 were you able to fix/workaround this issue?